# mongodb: how can I see the execution time for the aggregate command?

Tags: mongodb

I execute the follow mongodb command in mongo shell

```
db.coll.aggregate(...)
```

and i see the list of result. but is it possible to see the query
execution time? Is there any equivalent function for explain method for aggregation queries.

Comment: No, an explain does not exist yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504 so it is very hard to benchmark an aggregation query atm.

Comment: you could write a hack:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will write an answer to explain this better.

Basically there is no explain() functionality for the aggregation framework yet: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504

However there is a way to measure client side but not without its downsides:

- You are not measuring the database
- You are measuring the application
- There are too many unknowns about the in between parts to be able to get an accurate reading, i.e. you can't say that it took 0.04ms for the document result to be formulated by the MongoDB server, serialised, sent over the wire, de-serialised by the app and then stored into a hash allowing you subtract that sum from the total to get a aggregation benchmark.

However that being said, you might be able to get a slightly accurate result by doing it in MongoDB console on the same server as the `mongos` / `mongod`. This will create very little in betweens, still too many but enough to maybe get a reading you could roughly trust. As such you could use @Zagorulkin's answer in that position.

Comment: I would like to mention that as of 2.6 this answer is out of date, there is an explain() right on the aggregate() command now

Comment: I don't think the new `explain: true` option in `aggregate` gives execution time - just query planning info

Comment: No it measures the explain query again now

Comment: The JIRA ticket has been closed already and MongoDB has `explain` for `aggregate()`.

Answer (score 37):

```
var before = new Date()
#aggregation query
var after = new Date()
execution_mills = after - before
```

Comment: This is the most accurate way atm unfortunately however it is not as accurate as what the OP is asking for due to measuring the applications runtime not the databases.

Comment: d = new Date; db.coll.aggregate(...); print(new Date - d + 'ms'), succinctly.

Answer (score 17):

You can add a `time` function to your [`.mongorc.js`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#mongorc-js-file) file (in your home directory):

```
function time(command) {
    const t1 = new Date();
    const result = command();
    const t2 = new Date();
    print("time: " + (t2 - t1) + "ms");
    return result; 
}
```

and then you can use it like so:

```
time(() => db.coll.aggregate(...))
```

---

**Caution**

This method doesn't give relevant results for `db.collection.find()`

Comment: The timing is displayed, even seconds before the results from the database are returned.

Comment: @Complexity are you sure you passed your query as a function (`() => ...`)?

Comment: I did. This is the query and the output: `mongos> time(() => db["article.[L]"].find({"seo.keywords": "boor"}))
time required to execute the function: 0 milliseconds.` After this line, it takes 2 seconds to get the results, so why does the timing function come back so fast?

Comment: I will check it. My solution is basically the same approach as the most upvoted one. The only difference is that I put it in a function and saved in `.mongorc.js` so it's more convenient to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this to count performance on a sharded collection. The query is executed from a Mongo Router.

Comment: @Complexity Ok, I confirm that this method doesn't work for `db.collection.find()`. I guess it's because `.find()` returns a cursor immediately and fetches the data afterwards. Anyways, the question was about measuring time of aggregation ;) For testing performance of `find()` you can use `db.collection.find().explain()` and it will give you the execution time among other stats.

Comment: Thanks, Didn't realize than Mongo returns a cursor. If you edit your answer, I can upvote your answer :-)

Answer (score 12):

i see that in mongodb there is a possibility to use this two command:

- db.setProfilingLevel(2)
- and so after the query you can use db.system.profile.find() to see the query execution time and other

Comment: What fields in profile.find() output represent query time?

Comment: One line example: `db.system.profile.drop(); db.setProfilingLevel(2); db.collection.aggregate([ <pipeline> ]); db.setProfilingLevel(0); db.system.profile.findOne().millis`

Answer (score 10):

Or you can install the excellent [mongo-hacker](https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker), which automatically times every query, `pretty()`fies it, colorizes the output, sorts the keys, and more:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for the find() command, not for aggregate().

Answer (score 1):

Yes, now you can use an explain() in your aggregations from mongosh. For that you'd just need to add the following to your command ->
`db.yourCollectionName.explain("executionStats").aggregate(<yourAggregationStages>)`

and then you can see the response contains execution stats as well for the aggregation supplied. This is the format you'd see:

`executionStats: { executionSuccess: true, executionTimeMillis: '5.833', planningTimeMillis: '0.461', executionStages: { stage: 'SUBSCAN', nReturned: '1', executionTimeMillisEstimate: '5.124', ...`