# How to get the time stamp difference of the first and the last records that are inserted into a collection of mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How can we use this particular code in the execution process:

```
now = new Date();
current_date = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
end_date = obj.end_date (Mon, 02 Apr 2012 20:16:35 GMT);
var millisDiff = end_date.getTime() -  current_date.getTime();
console.log(millisDiff / 1000);
```

I have already inserted my records into a collection. It consists of many parameters. The first record tells the status to be started and the last record tells that the process has ended. They also consist of the time stamp values in all the records on when it started and when it ended.

How can I get the difference in time between the two processes? How can I use the above code?

```
db.trials.insert( { _id: ObjectId("51d2750d16257024e046c0d7"), Application: "xxx", ProcessContext: "SEARCH", InteractionID: "I001", opID: "BBB", buID: "Default", HostName: "xxx-ttt-tgd-002", InstanceName: "Instance1", EventTime: ISODate("2011-11-03T14:23:00Z"), HOPID: "", HOPName: "", HOPStatus: "", INTStatus: "Started" } );
db.trials.insert( { _id: ObjectId("51d2750d16257024e046c0d7"), Application: "xxx", ProcessContext: "SEARCH", InteractionID: "I001", opID: "BBB", buID: "Default", HostName: "xxx-ttt-tgd-002", InstanceName: "Instance1", EventTime: ISODate("2011-11-03T14:23:58Z"), HOPID: "", HOPName: "", HOPStatus: "", INTStatus: "Started" } );
```

These are the 2 records for which I wanted to know the time stamp difference using the above logic. How can I use the logic such that I can get the difference?

Comment: Which programming language are you targeting? The above code seems to be JavaScript...

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021605/mongodb-how-can-i-see-the-execution-time-for-the-aggregate-command/14022199#14022199

Comment: Please provide samples of your documents, and the expected output.

Comment: Hello, i can i use this below logic to execute a query???
var before = new Date()
#aggregation query
var after = new Date()
execution_mills = after - before