# mongoDB get execution time of a query in microseconds

Tags: php, mongodb, time, execution

I should get the execution time of a query in mongoDB. Using explain() I noticed that it is zero millis. So, Is it possible in mongoDB to obtain the execution time of a query in microseconds in a simple way?
For example if I wanted to calculate mean and variance of a sample of 10k test queries (where each query lasts micros), how could I do?
I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these links, they may be helpful for you

[Track MongoDB performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400104/track-mongodb-performance)

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: The second link is about profiling; the first link is about explain() (that returns time in ms) and also profiling. This latter allows me to log additional infos like: lock and unlock time, execution time (in millis) etc. Two questions: (i) Is the execution time of a query the sum of these locks time? (ii) if I execute a query n times, the profile will record just few. Why?

Comment: ans (i): the execution time doesn't include lock time, refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/            and check system.profile.lockStats.timeLockedMicros.   Ans(ii)db.system.profile.find() should show you all the records

Answer (score 1):

As answered here
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/14022199/5374951

```
var before = new Date()
#aggregation query
var after = new Date()
execution_mills = after - before
```

**Or**

```
d = new Date; db.coll.aggregate(...); 
print(new Date - d + 'ms')
```